# Get the list of Connections/Contacts from Linkedin for a specific user

Tags: linkedin-api

We have a requirement to fetch the list of Linkedin connections through an api call by passing the user id. On doing some research I could find there are few connections API, but there is restricted access on them and we can not test those API unless we have permissions for those. How we can get access to those apis and is there any other approach to fetch linkedin connections?

Tried to used Linkedin Connections api but their access is restricted. Please suggest any other way to get the connections